# setting Response.Cookies[ASP.NET_SessionId].Secure = true; in code clears my HttpContext.Current.Session["anyData"]

Tags: c#, asp.net, config, httpcontext

I want to set 'Response.Cookies[ASP.NET_SessionId].Secure = true'. I was trying to do it in master page so that on every page load 'ASP.NET_SessionId' will be marked as secure. However, when i write this code, my HttpContext.Current.Session is all erased.

Can someone help how this works and what can be the solution

Answer (score 0):

How Session cookie gets created ?

> > ASP.NET fires the session_start event on very first request and creates an "ASP.NET_SessionId" cookie on client browser.

Session getting erased ?

> > Can you check if your browser is sending the same session cookie value as originally created on first request? Ideally, asp.net identifies and track user's session based on the cookie value.

Share relevant code if that permits you.

Thanks